# Apache Solr - Lucene - Zip Code Radius Search

Tags: collections, solr, lucene, spatial-query

I have an existing collection of PERSON's records already loaded to my Solr Server. Each record has a field for a ZIPCODE. I know that Solr now supports spatial search with the `geodist()` function, the problem is that I do not have the `lat` and `long` for each person.

Can I add another collection to Solr mapping the ZipCodes to LATs and LONGs then JOIN them like you would with SQL? Is this even possible with Solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to translate `Zipcode` to `Lat/Long` in Solr.

Most Geospatial queries (not restricted to Solr) use Latitude and Longitude to perform a radius search. So this isn't a Solr specific problem.

I would recommend enriching the data that is imported into Solr using a [GeoCoding API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354490/latitude-and-longitude-based-on-zip-code).

You can update your existing index to have these fields populated for every document, but if possible I would prefer recreating the Solr Index with this data.

<del>I wouldn't include another collection for this purpose, JOIN isn't supported in Solr, as it isn't a relational data store.</del>

Edit:
Solr does [support](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) JOIN, but in your case I would still not go for it, unless I have to.